# How to set file directory slashes in php?

Tags: php

I want to specify the location of the 'upload' folder which contains the images uploaded. Now I want to display an image in post.php >>myblog is the root folder in htdocs xampserver >>'myblog/folder1/folder2/admin/Post.php' and the upload folder exists in the root folder 'myblog/upload'
I Only want to know how to understand the logic of slashes(forward and back slashes)

I'have tried first

```
    <td><img src="../Uploads/<?php echo $Image ; ?>"</td>
```

Then

```
    <td><img src="../..//Uploads/<?php echo $Image ; ?>"</td>
```

Then

```
    <td><img src="./../..//Uploads/<?php echo $Image ; ?>" width="170px;" height="50px"</td>
```

But none of these slashes worked

```
    <td><img src="..//Uploads/<?php echo $Image ; ?>" width="170px;" height="50px"</td>
```

Comment: You have not closed the <img tag before the </td>

Comment: Double slashes '//' is the same as single slashes.

Comment: ok. how can I specify the upload folder in the source of the image ?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to write URL's to assets in HTML.

#### Relative from the current URL

If you write

```
<img src="Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

and the URL is `example.com/some/subpage`, then the browser will try to load the image from `example.com/some/subpage/Uploads/image.jpg`.

If you write

```
<img src="../Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

the browser will, just like a file system, try to go up one level and load it from there: `example.com/some/Uploads/image.jpg`.

So this method is very much dependent on the current URL, which means that the image URL would need to be different (how many `../` you need etc) on different pages (if they are sub pages in sub pages etc). This is not a good way of doing it.

#### Relative from the document root

If you write

```
<img src="/Uploads/image.jpg" />
```

*(Notice the `/` in the beginning)*
the browser will try to load it from the document root (the same folder you have your `index.php` in): `example.com/Uploads/image.jpg`.

The good thing about this method is that the current page URL is irrelevant. If the `Upload`-folder is in the document root, just do `/Uploads/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a website with multiple pages is a good idea to put a "base tag" from which all other links are concatenated.
Here is a very good example that suits your needs:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

If your folder is somewhere in the public directory. Let's say
xampp/project/uploads/

Your base tag is probably "http://localhost/project/". After that you can set a relative url for the images like "uploads/image-name.jpg"